# Data Binding in Combobox

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I binded a database table's primary key to the selectedIndex of a combobox. the problem occurs where the primary key starts from 1 but selectedIndex accepts from 0. I mean, when I want to see the item with ID=1 in database, since it's listed as first element in combobox with index 0, it displays the second element in the list, which is considered with ID=1 in the combobox. Can anyone help me on solving this problem?

Thanks in advance.
here's my combobox:

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding SC.User1.UserID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"         
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          x:Name="proxyResponsibleUserCmb" ItemsSource="{Binding Users, Mode=OneTime}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SC.User1.FullName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,                   
                         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"  
          Height="23" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Width="118" 
          Margin="184,3,0,0" 
          Grid.Row="0" 
          Grid.Column="1"/>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code? E.g. if your selectedIndex is a property, why not do the calculation there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using the ComboBox's `SelectedValuePath` and `DisplayMemberPath`, and setting your default item with SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem?

```
<ComboBox x:Name="proxyResponsibleUserCmb" 
    SelectedValuePath="{Binding UserID}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="{Binding FullName}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SC.User1.UserId, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Users, Mode=OneTime}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Does setting the property `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` (in your XAML) to `True` help?

**EDIT**
Maybe this link will help:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/b4e84ea2-9597-4af1-8d3c-835b972e3d73

Answer (score 0):

Quick workaround via a ValueConverter:

Create a ValueConverter in your codebehind:

```
// of course use your own namespace...
namespace MyNameSpace
{
public class IndexConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(!(value is int)) // Add the breakpoint here!!
            throw new Exception();
        int newindex = ((int)value - 1;
        return newindex;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("This method should never be called");
    }
}
}
```

Then, make it known in your XAML:

```
//(declare a namespace in your window tag:)
xmlns:myNamespace="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace"

// add:
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <myNamespace:IndexConverter x:Key="indexConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then change your binding:

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding SC.User1.UserID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource indexConverter}}" ... />
```

That should do the trick. At least you can debug it by inserting a breakpoint in the IndexConverter.

Comment: Thank you for  your solution but ı realized that the trick will fail when a User is deleted from the database and thus the order is not synchronised with combobox's indexes anymore.
so I still need another solution to be able to make the right one to be selected.

Comment: Now I can update the selected item -I can see it by debugging- but I can't see it in combobox as selected. There is nothing displayed in combobox. Do you have any idea about why it happens and how it is solved?

Comment: If you want your combobox to update on data changes without reloading the page, you should consider putting a ViewModel in between and bind to its ObservableCollection or at least to some property which can raise an OnPropertyChanged event. My solution is quick'n'dirty for static database data.