# ComboBox with multi-binding as selected item?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am trying to do the following:

[Data Binding in Combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572816/data-binding-in-combobox)

but with multi-binding.. which means I want more than one binding..

So I can display, for example, fullname as  firstname + lastname.

How can we do that ?

Thanks!

Comment: I do not think such a binding should be set on the SelectedItem, which should govern what is selected, not what is displayed..

Comment: Well to be a bit clear that not on the selecteditem but what is shown to user.. the list of object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add an [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) like this:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, {1}">
                    <Binding Path="LastName" />
                    <Binding Path="FirstName" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

([`StringFormat` Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx))

*Sidenote: In actual code i more often use [Dean's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026123/combobox-with-multi-binding-as-selected-item/7026317#7026317), but this is the MultiBinding way of doing things.*

Comment: What the advantage comparing to Dean method ?

Comment: @Rushino: Depending on the complexity of the string format it is simply shorter (albeit less pure).

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean something simple like this

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <Run Text=" " />
                <Run Text="{Binding LastName}" />
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: A multi-binding is more elegant.

Comment: No, SelectedItem would be the data item bound to

Comment: Could you explain a bit ? What are the "RUN" doing exactly ?

Comment: A run is a part of a textblock, it can have its own styles etc

Comment: Just trying to figure out the advantage of using this instead of H.B. method.. ?

Comment: I believe my method is more in line with the consensus of best practices, although its debateable. Also, if either FirstName or LastName are null then you'll get a NullReferenceException in the HB method

Comment: I tried it and it gave me error in the XAML. It say that text binding cannot be done in run that it can only be done with dependencyobject.

Comment: @Rushino: Are you using .NET 3.5? [MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run.text.aspx) `Starting in the .NET Framework 4, the Text property of the Run object is a dependency property`

Comment: Yes ? Oh well that may explain why. That what i though at first..Anyway the project is being developped in 3.5 but will be converted in 4 pretty soon. So this gonna work in 4?

Comment: @Rushino: (Unless you directly address people in someone else's comment thread using `@UserName` they will not be notified)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a binding as MultiBinding as follows:

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter=" ... " ... >
      <Binding Path="FirstName" />
      <Binding Path="LastName" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks but why would i use a converter ? I can't give +1 cause it lack the principal stuff.. the itemtemplate otherwise it would have worked i guess. Just didn't know where to put your code.

Comment: Never mind for the vote. I think you're missing of the basics concepts of templating and bindings. The combo control is one of the most complex controls among the primitives. I was assuming you knew already how to apply a DataTemplate and how to create a simple binding. My snippet was a generic example on how to apply the multibinding. I consider that the question is how the multi-binding is working, not to solve your particular problem. I would suggest you to begin with simpler stuffs, otherwise you'll get confused within a short time.

Comment: Well your right about saying i am missing a lots of concept in WPF. I am rather new to this. Actually i am trying to learn it the hardcore way. I may get a book on that. But thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Create MultiBinding like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:WpfTestApp="clr-namespace:WpfTestApp" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
<Window.Resources>
    <WpfTestApp:ConcatenateStringsConverter x:Key="_concatenateStringsConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Style="{StaticResource RectangleHighlighter}">
    <ComboBox Width="200" Height="40">
        <ComboBox.Items>
            <ComboBoxItem >
                <ComboBoxItem.Content>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource _concatenateStringsConverter}">
                                <Binding Mode="OneWay" Path="FirstName" />
                                <Binding Mode="OneWay" Path="LastName" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </ComboBoxItem.Content>
            </ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox.Items>
    </ComboBox>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

I have used MainWindowViewModel as the Window's DataContext:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}


public class MainWindowViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        FirstName = "Souvik";
        LastName = "Basu";
    }


    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            if (_firstName != value)
            {
                _firstName = value;
                OnPropertyChange("FirstName");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            if (_lastName != value)
            {
                _lastName = value;
                OnPropertyChange("LastName");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The converter concatenates the multiple binding values..

```
class ConcatenateStringsConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values[0].ToString() + " " + values[1].ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example given here is almost what you need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx

Just swap the TextBlock for a ComboBox and bind to its SelectedItem rather than the Text property.

Comment: this talk about a converter.. nothing related really to what i needed. It doesn't even show how to apply to a combobox.

Comment: I voted for @H.B.'s solution because it best answers your question. Bear in mind though that your requirements would not need to change much before you would outgrow StringFormat. A converter could handle displaying the first and last name separated by a space if both are available and only the first name (without a space) if the last name were null for example.